# How to limit a firebase database 'write' instruction to only allow a specific userID?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am writing a firebase database app which allows a webcam image to be sent through firebase at the rate of one pixel per second. The database is then read at another website which recombines the pixels into an image.

The database is trivial just an x,y position and r,g,b values.

```
var db;
var dbname = 'webcam';
var data = {
  x : 0,
  y : 0,
  r : 0,
  g : 0,
  b : 0
};
```

So only one pixel at a time is stored in the database. To send data to the database I use this javascript function :

```
function updateDB(x,y,r,g,b){
  data.x = x;
  data.y = y;
  data.r = r;
  data.g = g;
  data.b = b;
  if(db != null){ db.ref(dbname).set(data); } 
}
```

The database has been instantiated like this

```
function setupFirebase() {
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  db = firebase.database();
}
```

The rules for the database are completely open :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

This is working - I can read from the database using this javascipt function. The data is put into the webcam[][] array and is drawn to the screen in a browser window.

```
db.ref(dbname).on("value", function gotdata(newdata) {
  fbdata = newdata.val();
  if (fbdata != null) {
    //send data to the image grid
    var x = fbdata.x;
    var y = fbdata.y;
    var r = fbdata.r;
    var g = fbdata.g;
    var b = fbdata.b;
    //console.log("webcam data arrived = ", x, y, r, g, b);
    webcam[x][y] = r;
    webcam[x][y] = g;
    webcam[x][y] = b;
  }
});
```

Here is the problem. I want to add Authentication so that only I can send the pixel information from my web app. I want anyone to be able to read the image, but only I can write the image. I have generated a userID by using email + password Authentication in Firebase, which gives me a userID of for example = "12345678901234567890".

In the database rules I set the rules to this :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",  
    ".write": "auth.uid === '12345678901234567890'"
  }
}
```

It just generates error messages in the browser as expected.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at Repo.ts:751
    at Ft (util.ts:539)
    at Ki.callOnCompleteCallback (Repo.ts:741)
    at Repo.ts:463
    at PersistentConnection.ts:613
    at Mi.onDataMessage_ (PersistentConnection.ts:648)
    at xi.onDataMessage_ (Connection.ts:314)
    at xi.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (Connection.ts:306)
    at Pi.onMessage (Connection.ts:203)
    at Pi.appendFrame_ (WebSocketConnection.ts:275)
```

The question is where do I use this userID in the javascript app that sends the pixels to the database? How do I let the database know that I have a valid userID? Do I do this once on in the firebaseConfig(), or does it need to be sent every time I send a piece of pixel data?

I can't find a clear example of this simple transaction in the Firebase reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To give the `auth.uid` variable in your security rules a value, you'll need to sign in with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users). Since you don't seem to really care about credentials, you can anonymous authentication, log the user's UID, and then put that value in your security rules.

Once you're signed in, the Firebase SDKs will automatically send the ID token of the user with each connection, and the server will then verify that ID token, and pass the information (including the UID) in the `auth` variable of the security rules.

Comment: Thanks. So I've done the first part: putting the userID in the security rules. Now in a webbased javascript app I want to access the db. I do the usual firebaseConfig and initialize the app, but how do I tell firebase that I am using my userID? I don't need to sign in necessarily as there is only one user - me. I could just directly give it the userId generated in the console.

Comment: I want to do something like - firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, myUserID);

Comment: The code in your question does not show that you're signing in with Firebase Authentication. Only once you sign the user in with Firebase Authentication will the the `auth` variable in the security rules get a value. Please check the documentation that I linked in my answer to learn how to sign in with Firebase Authentication.